# Is these 2 grammars equal?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, lr-grammar

I have the following grammar which is ambiguous and of course not slr1:

```
E -> E+A+A | E+A-A | E-A+A | E-A-A | T
T -> T+A | T-A | A
A -> A*B | A/B | B
B -> (E) | x
```

I used the rule of transformation which is:

```
E -> E + T  ----->  E -> TE'
                    E' -> +TE' | ε
```

so the first grammar transforms into this:

```
E -> T E' .
E' -> + A + A E' .
E' -> + A - A E' .
E' -> - A + A E' .
E' -> - A - A E' .
E' -> .
T -> A T' .
T' -> + A T' .
T' -> - A T' .
T' -> .
A -> B A' .
A' -> * B A' .
A' -> / B A' .
A' -> .
B -> ( E ) .
B -> x .
```

This is solving the ambiguity but it continues not being slr1. The transformation is correct. After that I erase the T rules and I install them to E'. So the final grammar which is slr1 is the following:

```
E -> A E' .
E' -> + A + A E' .
E' -> + A - A E' .
E' -> - A + A E' .
E' -> - A - A E' .
E' -> + A .
E' -> - A .
E' -> .
A -> B A' .
A' -> * B A' .
A' -> / B A' .
A' -> .
B -> ( E ) .
B -> x .
```

Now I have 2 questions.

1. The 2 final grammars are equal ?? I define equality by saying that these 2 grammars must accept the same sentences. It seems that they do.
2. Is the fact that i erased the T rules correct ?? My exercise ask that I change the very first one to slr1 and all i came up with was the final one. Thx in advanced and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that your assignment is marked by someone who provides good feedback. I would like to believe that higher education still works in some places, but obviously that is a bit of an illusion.

Anyway. The grammar you end up with is a valid solution to the problem as you present it, but the solution is based on a misconception and an error, which coincidentally cancel each other out to produce a valid result.

First, the misconception: left-recursion is not the same as ambiguity, and consequently left-factoring and eliminating left-recursion does not remove ambiguity. In particular, your claim that "This is solving the ambiguity but it continues not being SLR(1)" is mistaken. The transformation does not remove the ambiguity; the grammar continues to not be SLR(1) because it is still ambiguous.

```
E                   E
T E'                T E'
A T' E'             A T' E'
B A' T' E'          B A' T' E'
x A' T' E'          x A' T' E'
x T' E'             x T' E'
x + A T' E'         x E'
x + B A' T' E'      x + A + A E'
x + x A' T' E'      x + B A' + A E'
x + x T' E'         x + x A' + A E'
x + x + A T' E'     x + x + A E'
x + x + B A' T' E'  x + x + B A' E'
x + x + x A' T' E'  x + x + x A' E'
x + x + x T' E'     x + x + x E'
x + x + x E'        x + x + x
x + x + x
```

The mistake is the erasure of the `T` rules. You start with

```
E -> T E' .
T -> A T' .
T' -> + A T' .
T' -> - A T' .
T' -> .
```

From that, you can easily erase `T`, since it is only used in one place:

```
E -> A T' E'.
T' -> + A T' .
T' -> - A T' .
T' -> .
```

Erasing `T'` is not so simple, though, because it is recursive. And, in any event, `E'` does not have any production which uses `T'`, so adding new productions to `E'` is not a mechanical elimination of `T'`.

However, the productions you choose to add to `E'` do, in fact, eliminate the ambiguity. So well done, in that sense. But note that you could have done this without the left-recursion elimination:

```
E -> E + A + A .
E -> E + A - A .
E -> E - A + A .
E -> E - A - A .
E -> A + A .
E -> A - A .
E -> A .
A -> A * B .
A -> A / B .
A -> B .
B -> ( E ) .
B -> x .
```

That grammar is unambiguous, for the same reason yours is: the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> operators are decomposed into a sequence of ternary operations, possibly preceded by a single binary operation (in case the sequence of additive operators contains an odd number of operators). But it is not SLR(1). Indeed, it is not LR(k) for any k, because it is impossible to know whether the sequence of operations should start with a ternary or binary operation until we know whether there are an even or odd number of operators.

But we can solve that problem (in effect, in the same way as your grammar) by making the additive operators right-associative:

```
E -> A + A + E .
E -> A + A - E .
E -> A - A + E .
E -> A - A - E .
# Rest of the grammar is the same
```

This grammar is not LL(1), of course; it is not left-factored. But the original problem did not require an LL(1) grammar, and the above is SLR(1).

However, that is just one possible interpretation of the original ambiguous grammar, and quite possibly not the most natural one since right-associativity is not usually the natural interpretation. Unless the problem specifies a desired associativity, there is no way to know what is desired.

Comment: I am going to disappoint you because I and my colleagues aren't getting a feedback at all. In Greece crisis touched universities and their quality after all. Thx for your answer and your explanation as I understood everything.I will stick to your solution ,I spent a week trying to find it and couldn't believe that little change you did solve the problem! I guess the key was to understand where the ambiguity was. Anyway another question rose ,I know how to construct LR(1) tables etc but how you know that this is not LR(k)? I thought that you have to know the string before in order to understand

Comment: How do you derive `x + x +`?

Comment: @kostas: the left-associative solution is more difficult, but it does exist as long as you prefer the ternary operator. That is, `x + x + x + x + x + x` must parse as `[+ [++ [++ x x x] x x] x]`. (My non-SLR(1) grammar produces `[++ [++ [+ x x] x x] x x]`.)

Comment: oh my bad i mix up things , yeah you are right. We cannot derive x+x+.

Comment: When we say left-associative solution we mean we can derive words from the left right ?? So can we transform this grammar (the final you posted) to produce words from the left ?? I don't quite understand the series of 'x' and '[' from the parser you describe. Thx for everything btw , you really make me understand some things

Comment: @kostas: we say that subtraction (for example) is left-associative because we parse `1 - 2 - 3` as though it were written `(1 - 2) - 3` (=-4) rather than `1 - (2 - 3)` (=2). Of the standard arithmetic operators, only exponentiation associates to the right. Both left- and right- associative operators can be parsed left-to-right with an LR(k) parser; left-associative operators use left-recursive productions and right-associative operators right-recursion. Because LL(k) parsers cannot handle left-recursion, they always produce right-associative parses, which need to be adjusted...

Comment: ...by semantic rules. (Which is one of the reasons that I don't see the point spending much time on LL(k) parsing; more importantly, LL(k) grammars are much harder to read, imho.)

Comment: I used `[…]` in my parse to bracket productions, effectively writing the parse tree as a preorder walk. The ternary productions correspond to ternary nodes in the parse tree; since not all nodes are binary, some kind of bracketing is necessary. I didn't have the patience to draw out the trees as ASCII art, but drawing the trees is a good exercise in understanding the parse so I encourage you to try it.

Comment: @kostas, finally I sympathize with your academic plght; here in Perú -- and without the excuse of a "crisis" -- many universities are similarly unresponsive to the needs of their students. Good luck.